# Moving things position within a container in wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have this problem, I want to adjust the position of an image or the hole canvas inside my container which is a 'border', it is more likely a translate transform but depending on the user by moving this element around to adjust it to the suitable position, because my program needs an accurate coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar, just placed the canvas in another canvas so i could move it around more easily.